# Memory management in Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to learn Objective-C and iOS development. In [the book I'm reading](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321821521) there is a chapter on memory management. Is this a concept that I need to be familiar with? It seems like most memory management is done automatically now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no automatic "run-time" memory management in iOS. If the book mentions "ARC" or "Automatic Reference Counting", it simply means that you have to write less memory management code. ARC inserts a lot of memory management code during compile time for you.

Yes, you definitely need to be familiar with memory management. It's a bit tricky to dive right into ARC without learning how it used to be without ARC. I'd suggest learning how to write non-ARC code first. Once you have gotten used to it, then enable ARC in your code.

Answer (score 2):

iOS programming used to require manual memory management, but this is not the case anymore.

With ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) the compiler will pretty much handle memory management for you (memory deallocations), if you program for iOS 5.0+ (Which should be mandatory by now). I suggest you read up on ARC and how to make weak references etc.

Note that the compiler will not stop you from never releasing objects and eating up all available memory, so you still need to figure out when to get rid of objects.